# Why does sample covariance matrix inflates the larger eigenvalues and shrinks the smaller eigenvalues of the covariance matrix?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, machine-learning, estimation

In classification context, using the maximum likelihood, the sample covariance matrix for each class, estimates the larger eigenvalues of the covariance matrix of each class, larger and estimates the smaller eigenvalues smaller. Why is that? I am studying Regularized Discriminant Analysis written by Friedman.

From [Regularized Discriminant Analysis](http://www.leg.ufpr.br/%7Eeferreira/CE064/Regularized%20Discriminant%20Analysis.pdf) Jerome H. Friedman, Journal of the American Statistical Association, Vol. 84, No. 405 (Mar., 1989), pp. 165-175 (original [source](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2289860?seq=1)):

> It is well known that the estimates based on Equation (12) produce biased estimates of the eigenvalues; the largest ones are biased high and the smallest ones are biased toward values that are too low. This bias is most pronounced when the population eigenvalues tend toward equality, and it is correspondingly less severe when their values are highly disparate. In all cases, this phenomenon becomes more pronounced as the sample size decreases. When $N_k \le p$ the sample covariance matrix is singular with rank $\le N_k$ and the smallest $p - N_k + 1$ eigenvalues are estimated to be 0. The corresponding eigenvectors are then arbitrary, subject perhaps to orthogonality constraint

Comment: That sounds interesting. Where did you get this assertion?

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi07sHtv9rbAhWBsBQKHY6DBE0QFghYMAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.leg.ufpr.br%2Flib%2Fexe%2Ffetch.php%3Ftok%3D279ed1%26media%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.leg.ufpr.br%252F~eferreira%252FCE064%252FRegularized%2520Discriminant%2520Analysis.pdf&usg=AOvVaw04XWPHIYj8Xn66_b2hPZDF
On the third page of this pdf, two paragraphs after equation 13. It says "it is well known"

Comment: @CaveJohnson I've moved the information back into the question; it will be visible as soon as the edit is approved

Comment: I think, intuitively we can make some sense of this: consider the case when sampling uniformly from a circle. If you have only 3 points, the estimated eigenvalues are very likely to skewed. Only when the 3 sampled points happen to form approximately a uniform triangle - which is unlikely - the estimate of the eigenvalues will be good. This problem will amplify in higher dimensional space due to the concentration of measure effect.